# Cannot inject $ionicHistory into my ionic application angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Cannot inject $ionicHistory into my ionic application angularjs controller

**ERROR :**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $ionicHistoryProvider <- $ionicHistory
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17/$injector/unpr?p0=NaNonicHistoryProvider%20%3C-%20%24ionicHistory
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:7942:12
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11599:19
at Object.getService as get
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11604:45
at getService (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11726:39)
at invoke (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11753:13)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11774:23)
at $get (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15028:28)
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14430:34
at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8191:20)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:17763$get @ ionic.bundle.js:15110nodeLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:14474compositeLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:13871nodeLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:14465compositeLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:13875publicLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:13780boundTranscludeFn @ ionic.bundle.js:13894controllersBoundTransclude @ ionic.bundle.js:14492ngIfWatchAction @ ionic.bundle.js:27190$get.Scope.$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:20221$get.Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:20486done @ ionic.bundle.js:16098completeRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:16303xhr.onreadystatechange @ ionic.bundle.js:16242
ionic.bundle.js:17763 mobileapp details saved
```

Comment: *"Talk is cheap, show me the code!"*

Comment: In which order do you insert the .js files?